# Need help in generating values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've edited my query like below:

```
SELECT
    ser.SERVER_COMPONENT_NAME, ITServ.IT_SERVICE_BUSINESS_CRITICALIT, 
    app.APPCROWNJEWEL,
    MAX(CASE
           WHEN ITServ.IT_SERVICE_BUSINESS_CRITICALIT = 'Tier o' THEN 1
           WHEN ITServ.IT_SERVICE_BUSINESS_CRITICALIT = 'Tier 1' THEN 3
           WHEN ITServ.IT_SERVICE_BUSINESS_CRITICALIT = 'Tier 2' THEN 5
           WHEN ITServ.IT_SERVICE_BUSINESS_CRITICALIT IS NULL THEN 5
           ELSE 0
        END) AS TierRatingValue,
    MAX(CASE   
           WHEN app.APPCROWNJEWEL = 'Yes' THEN 3
           WHEN app.APPCROWNJEWEL = 'No' THEN 2
           ELSE 1
        END) AS JewelsValue
FROM
    TDM_FACT_SERVER ser 
LEFT JOIN 
    TDM_RKT_SM_TO_SERVER smServer ON smServer.SERVER_COMPONENT_ID = Ser.SERVER_COMPONENT_ID
                                  AND smServer.SOFTWARE_MODULE_COMPONENT_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT sm.SOFTWARE_MODULE_COMPONENT_ID 
                                                                                FROM software_module sm
                                                                                WHERE sm.SOFTWARE_MODULE_COMPONENT_NAME LIKE 'DBSM:%' OR  
                                                                                      sm.SOFTWARE_MODULE_COMPONENT_NAME LIKE 'MWSM:%' OR
                                                                                      sm.SOFTWARE_MODULE_COMPONENT_NAME like 'CMS:%')
LEFT JOIN 
    SOFTWARE_MODULE sm ON sm.SOFTWARE_MODULE_COMPONENT_ID = smServer.SOFTWARE_MODULE_COMPONENT_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    TDM_RKT_IT_SERVICE_TO_SM ITSERVICETOSM ON sm.SOFTWARE_MODULE_COMPONENT_ID = ITSERVICETOSM.SOFTWARE_MODULE_COMPONENT_ID
                                           AND ITSERVICETOSM.IT_SERVICE_COMPONENT_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT Itserv.IT_SERVICE_COMPONENT_ID
                                                                                         FROM tdm_fact_it_srvc Itserv
                                                                                         WHERE Itserv.IT_SERVICE_SERVICE_RECONCILIAT IN ('Active in PLADA but not present in GSD', 
                                                                                                                                         'Active in GSD but not present in PLADA',
                                                                                                                                         'Active in GSD and PLADA',
                                                                                                                                         'Active in GSD but demised in PLADA',
                                                                                                                                         'Active in PLADA but demised in GSD'))    
LEFT JOIN 
    TDM_FACT_IT_SRVC ITServ ON ITSERVICETOSM.IT_SERVICE_COMPONENT_ID = ITServ.IT_SERVICE_COMPONENT_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    TDM_RKT_APP_TO_ITSERVICE ApptoITService ON ITServ.IT_SERVICE_COMPONENT_ID = ApptoITService.IT_SERVICE_COMPONENT_ID
LEFT JOIN  
    hsbc_ci_inventory_as app ON ApptoITService.APPLICATION_COMPONENT_ID = app.appid
WHERE 
    ser.SERVER_COMPONENT_NAME = 'GBL03427'
GROUP BY 
    ser.SERVER_COMPONENT_NAME, ITServ.IT_SERVICE_BUSINESS_CRITICALIT, 
    app.APPCROWNJEWEL
```

Below is the output as it is generating two new columns as expected.

```
Server          TierRating   Jewels         TierRatingValue      JewelsValue
---------       ----------   ----------     ----------------     -----------
GBL03427          Tier 0     No                 0                    2
GBL03427          Tier 1     Yes                3                    3
GBL03427          Tier 2     Undefined          5                    1
GBL03427          Tier 1     No                 3                    2
GBL03427          Tier 2     No                 5                    2
GBL03427          Tier 0     Yes                0                    3
GBL03427          Tier 1     NULL               3                    1
GBL03427          NULL       NULL               5                    1
GBL03427          Tier 1     Undefined          3                    1
GBL03427          Tier 0     Undefined          0                    1
```

But I would like to see the output as one line with the max value of TierRatingValue and JewelsValue as below.

```
Server      TierRating   Jewels         TierRatingValue      JewelsValue
---------   ----------   ----------     ----------------     -----------
GBL03427    Tier 2       Yes                5                   3
```

Comment: Please tag the correct database you are using.. MySQL, SQL-server and SQLite are not the same..

Comment: It would also help if you would provide sample data (e.g. as insert into statements or by a with clause). Did you try a "Group By"-Clause? E.g. Select ... Group by TierRating.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, ***please*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: You have completely changed the question, which is something you should not do. The original question may be added to if necessary; but hiding the original question makes original answers seem off-topic. This recent change to the question should have been a new question I believe. Also look at HELP (in the footnote) about how to ask questions.

Comment: I saw comment from Imran to edit the same in the question that’s why i did it. I’m new to this page and I don’t know if I can do that or not and I’m so sorry for doing that. Do you want me to create it as a new question then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To substitute a value such as 5 if some existing value = 'Tier 0' you would use a `case expression`, which might look like this:

```
case
     when TierRating = 'Tier 0' then 1
     when TierRating = 'Tier 1' then 3
     when TierRating = 'Tier 2' then 5
     when TierRating IS NULL then 5
     when TierRating = 'Yes' then 3
     when TierRating = 'No' then 2
     else 1
end AS Tier_Rank
```

Assuming the case expression does use integers 1,2, etc then to arrive at a maximum value you can place the whole case expression inside a MAX() function like this:

```
MAX(
    case
         when TierRating = 'Tier o' then 1
         when TierRating = 'Tier 1' then 3
         when TierRating = 'Tier 2' then 5
         when TierRating IS NULL then 5
         when TierRating = 'Yes' then 3
         when TierRating = 'No' then 2
         else 1
    end
    ) AS Tier_Rank
```

and incorporate it like any other column of a query using a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've made changes to the query and edited the original question. Could you please help me on the edited question.